# Using batch normalization during test time but not in inference mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to tell a `tf.keras` model *to not use* the Batch Normalization in [inference mode](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) during prediction?

Comment: May i know reason why do you not use Batch normalization in Inference Data ? I hope this reference helps you https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html and https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L170

Comment: Using Batch Normalization, not in inference mode and not using it at all are two different things. Read about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization